# Android onCreateOptionsMenu not called when hitting the menu button

Tags: android, menu

I have the problem that my application doesn't show the options menu when I hit the menu button. Debugging shows that the onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) method is not called after hitting the menu button. I have another application with the same code for the menu and there it works. So now my code:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.app_menu, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.options:
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, OptionsActivity.class);
            startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

}
```

In res -> menu -> app_menu.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
   <item android:id="@+id/options" android:title="@string/options" /> 
</menu>
```

I have no idea why the onCreateOptionsMenu is not called after hitting the menu button. I hope you guys can help me.

Edit: I'm not using Fragments and the onCreateOptionsMenu is really never called. Not at the start of the app and not when i'm hitting the menu button on my device.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure from your post that you're using Fragments. If so, you must set menu options on by

```
setHasOptionMenu(true);
```

call this method from Fragment's onCreate() and the options menu will then be shown.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add these item attributes in your `app_menu.xml` file:

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/options"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:showAsAction="never"
    android:title="@string/options"/>
```

You must declare a string for `options` in Strings.xml

Comment: Doesn't work for me and I have a string for options in the Strings.xml ;)

Answer (score 1):

It will call when app starts for the first time not after menu item selected.

```
@Override
    public boolean onMenuItemSelected(int featureId, MenuItem item) {
if (item.getItemId() == R.id.menuitem_id) {
}
return super.onMenuItemSelected(featureId, item);
}
```

this method will be called after selection

Comment: My onCreateOptionsMenu is never called, not at the start and not when I'am hitting the menu button on my device. But in another application with the same code it works..

Answer (score -1):

In Manifest file just set target versions as below:
android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="10"